# How to fetch data from employee table in mysql like below?

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have one table like this:

[image: Screenshot of table]

and desired result should be like this:

```
id    name  boss_name
101    a      null
102    b       a
103    c       b
104    d       b
```

How can I get this result using SQL?

Comment: can you reply on ans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    employee.id,
    employee.`name`,
    boss.`name` boss_name
FROM
    employee
LEFT JOIN employee boss ON (
    boss.id = employee.boss_id
)
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using self joing like:

```
SELLECT `user`.id,`user`.`name`,`boss`.`name` FROM `user` `user` left join `user` `boss` on (`boss`.`boss_id`=`user`.`id`)
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: The condition of left join should be this:`user`.`boss_id` = `boss`.`id`

Comment: Sory to say dear you are wrong because we have to find boos name which is also a user.. so i think my condition it right.